# Joomla custom Component Update Server script Issue

Tags: joomla

I am developing custom component Joomla 2.5 version.

Now I am trying to create  update  script / server, but it does not work.

Comment: please provide the code you are using for the update script.

Comment: We're all wizards here, thus not posting code or relevant information is perfectly fine as we can telepathically guess what you did wrong. But you forgot to mention the error you're getting. So the answer is: "Your markup is wrong".  We struggled for quite a while with update-related issues as well, there are quite a few things you could have done wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Check out Joomla docs on this topic:

- [J2.5:Developing a MVC Component/Adding an update server](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Adding_an_update_server),
- [Deploying an Update Server](http://docs.joomla.org/Deploying_an_Update_Server)
- [Akeeba Release System](https://www.akeebabackup.com/downloads/akeeba-release-system.html) for advanced package management

It's really hard to find out what's wrong from your description of problem.