# Joomla Component Update script

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component

I have my **self made component.** I want to know how can i pass an update of my component so that my clients using it can, if they wish to, update my component.

I basically have *added* a feature in my component and i want it to be updated in *already* deployed components

Comment: I just gave some hints to similar question yesterday: [Joomla custom Component Update Server script Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540057/joomla-custom-component-update-server-script-issue/16542820#16542820)

Comment: It's indeed a duplicate, but I don't have enough rep to flag it so.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the same component with full component package, joomla will automatically update the component with all the files in it as long as the method of the extension tag in extension installer xml file is set to upgrade.

for example in your install.xml or componentname.xml (whatever you use) file:

```
<extension type="component" version="2.5.0" method="upgrade">
```

if you would like to do some update scripts run or want to do some custom jobs before/after installation completed, you can use scriptfile.

```
<scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
```

Docs: http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file